# In comune o comune possono alternarsi?

Tags: grammar, difference

In comune o comune possono alternarsi?

1. Abbiamo dei sogni in comune/abbiamo sogni comuni
2. Abbiamo due caratteristiche comuni/in comune

Sul dizionario Treccani dei sinonimi e contrari per [comune](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/comune1_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/) non vi è una corrispondenza tra i due.

Vengono riportati solo gli altri significati che assume l'aggettivo.

Answer (score 7):

Abbiamo dei sogni in comune vuol dire che condividiamo dei sogni, io ho un sogno che è lo stesso che hai tu.

Abbiamo sogni comuni vuol dire che abbiamo sogni che è statisticamente molto facile che abbiano anche altri, tipo diventare famoso, etc.

Lo stesso dicasi per avere caratteristiche comuni, cioè che quasi tutti gli altri hanno e avere caratteristiche in comune, cioè condividere una serie di caratteristiche.

Quindi, in generale, il significato è diverso e perciò non si possono alternare.